# Calculated Field in Tableau Count Distinct with Condition

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to calculate the distinct number of IP Addresses in Tableau where the Year is 2020.

How can I do this in Tableau?

I've tried this..but it's not giving the right result:

`{FIXED [IP] : SUM(IIF[Year] = 2020,1,0))}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in COUNTD() function.

```
COUNTD(IF [YEAR] = 2020 THEN [IP] END)
```

Comment: You can also get a bit more flexibility by leaving the Countd() out of the calculated field - and then choosing the aggregation function on the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF DATETRUNC('month', [Created Date])=DATETRUNC('month',[PERFORMANCE_DATE])
THEN
COUNT([Slug Title])*31/28
ELSEIF DATETRUNC('month', [Created Date])< DATETRUNC('month',[PERFORMANCE_DATE])
THEN COUNT([Slug Title])
END

im trying to display is above condition is true then COUNT([Slug Title])*31/28 and if its false then only COUNT([Slug Title])
please resolve my above queries
```